# Typescript: Type with exactly one property of another type

Tags: typescript

I have interface and wanna make type using key of this interface.

- key can be optional
- key must be in that interface

Example

```js
interface Test {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d: string | undefined;
  e: string | undefined;
}
```

My new type can have one property among above keys. I wrote like below

```js
type MyNewType<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key];
};
```

I used this type as `MyNewType<Test>`, but encounters error.

> **Type '{ a: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'MyNewType': b, c, d, e.**

How can I use property optionally?

**Clarification**

I'm using reducer in React and calling `dispatch` function which accepts action creater as parameter. `Test` type is state type and `MyNewType<Test>` is payload type. Action creator accepts payload and payload can become `{ a: 'a'}`, `{ b: 'b' }`, or `{ d: undefined }`. However error says that payload has to contain all the properties.

Comment: "one property among above keys" --- what does this actually mean?

Comment: I use only one property when I pass parameter to function and type of paramter is `MyNewType<Test>`

Comment: You still need to clarify your request better: do you want a type with **only one** (and nothing else) property from the original object; or **at least** one? Or something else?

Comment: Maybe you should also edit the question title - "use property optionally" leads everyone to think you are searching for an answer such as the one @Lim Jing Rong provided.

Comment: @mperktold Good feedback, but I'm not good at English. Can you suggest one?

Comment: Just to clarify, by "optional" you mean that `{ }` should also be OK? So the object must contain zero or one property of the original type, but not more?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need a generic solution, you can use the following:

```
MyNewType = { a: string }
          | { b: string }
          | { c: string }
          | { d: string | undefined }
          | { d: string | undefined };
```

I cannot think of any way of doing this for a generic type `T`.

But you can use another approach: Instead of just selecting a single key value pair, you could use separate properties for key and value, e.g.:

```
{
  key: "a",
  value: "a"
}
```

This *can* be done in a generic way:

```
type MyNewType<T> = {
  key: keyof T;
  value: T[keyof T];
}
```

However, this is not very precise, as you can combine any key with any value.

Another approach would be:

```
type MyNewType<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  key: K;
  value: T[K];
}
```

Wich works as expected but introduces a new type parameter to represent the key type.
For example, you could use it as:

```
function dispatch<K extends keyof Test>(testPayload: MyNewType<Test, K>) {
  // do something with payload
}

dispatch({ key: "a", value: "a" });        // OK
dispatch({ key: "a", value: undefined });  // Error, because Test.a cannot be undefined
dispatch({ key: "d", value: undefined });  // OK
dispatch({ key: "x", value: undefined });  // Error, because Test does not have property "x"
```

**Edit**

I also tried the following to create a type exactly as requested:

```
type MyNewType<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  [key: K]: T[K];
}
```

But TypeScript gives the following error on `key`:

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `?` behind the keys that are optional

Example, if you want to make a & b optional

```
interface Test {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
  c: string;
  d: string | undefined;
  e: string | undefined;
}
```

Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#optional-properties

Comment: `a` and `b` cannot be `undefined`, the meaning of "optional" is parameter passing to function can be only one property

Answer (score 1):

The author of this question got it 99% right by himself. There's only one small `?` missing :)

It can be done by marking the key optional:

```
type MyNewType<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]?: T[key];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

### Generic solution

This works for me in TypeScript 5.0:

```js
type OneProp<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: { [_ in K]: T[K] }
}[keyof T]
```

#### Explanation

To demonstrate, the following type:

```
type Foo = OneProp<{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}>
```

would expand to

```js
type Foo = {
    a: { a: 1 },
    b: { b: 2 },
    c: { c: 3 },
}['a' | 'b' | 'c']
```

and finally,

```js
type Foo = { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } | { c: 3 }
```

#### Usage

This function shows how testing membership is enough to infer the actual type:

```js
function getPropValue(x: OneProp<{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }>) {
    if ('a' in x) {
        // x is inferred to be { a: 1 } because it contains 'a'
        return x.a
    } else if ('b' in x) {
        // x is inferred to be { b: 2 } because it contains 'b'
        return x.b
    } else {
        // x is inferred to be { c: 3 } since it contains neither 'a' nor 'b'
        x.c
    }
}
```

#### Limitations

Technically, this type enforces that *at least* one of the properties of `T` is present--you won't get an error if more than one is present.

```js
type Foo = OneProp<{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }> // Evaluates to { a: 1 } | { b: 2 } | { c: 3 }

const test1: Foo = { a: 1 } // Ok
const test2: Foo = { b: 2, c: 3 } // Ok: This does NOT enforce that only one prop is provided
const test3: Foo = {} // ERROR: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a a similar problem, and came up with the following design.

Define an interface, or type, which contains every property you want to support, but make them all *optional* and type *never*. You *may* use any of these properties, but you can't assign anything to them.

```ts
interface BaseType {
  a?: never;
  b?: never;
  c?: never;
  d?: never;
  e?: never;
}
```

Create a type for each property by omitting the base *never* property and replacing it with the type you want, but now it's no longer optional.

```ts
type AType = Omit<BaseType, "a"> & { "a": string };
type BType = Omit<BaseType, "b"> & { "b": string };
type CType = Omit<BaseType, "c"> & { "c": string };
type DType = Omit<BaseType, "d"> & { "d": string | undefined };
type EType = Omit<BaseType, "e"> & { "e": string | undefined };
```

Combine all these single-property types to create your `MyNewType`. Any instance of this type must be one of the individual types above.

```ts
type MyNewType = AType | BType | CType | DType | EType;
```

The following lines either compile or trigger TypeScript errors:

```ts
let testA : MyNewType = { "a": "test" } // A is present, and is a string
let testB : MyNewType = { "b": 1 } // B is present, but cannot be a number 
let testD : MyNewType = { "d": undefined } // D is present, and may be undefined 
let testMultiple : MyNewType = { "a": "Some String", "b": "Another String" } // Cannot include multiple properties
```

I've also set this up in [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QCoE8AOKA3gLABQyycA-AFzIgQBu0A3OZQEZ0PNsfIEPRiyjsKyACbC%20YgRBmjxAX3LkwBFAEE8hZAF5kAeQC2wMAB50WXRAA0yAERxHAPmQAyZEScv6GMChQAHNkZXENPVRbA2MzS2scTQdHTjdPbyc0-0CQsIjNZABhGMNTcytMJMIUhHSvH0c6nKCQUPD1QoARUriKxNsUyXrMx2GWvIAfZABXEEkIGFAISXzOvQBRXvKEqsGnCBHGw4m25Gm5haXGVY6yNTJIlABZXAA5CAB3Xp1C6ei-sUYtMeoCtppxA8ADYQMDISABLTIeivD7fQqGRp%20JwIsCOMLIAD0hOQSOAGCki2Wqzg82Q5KoyACrWC5BhcNxqGRyFRX16jWyyAAjATiWh6RSrtSHJwZnCELSQAB7OGcFBwBgzExqqDINmw%20EQAJdbm89F6TFOcazeZUm6ikkmhlSm4OWmrExwXDINU2l0rPVkdmGgLPGZQsDAfAw03vPkY0bYxwAZSVJhQydybUcKUFji0yrAAAtoMhMyz8coiSSioqVZTrigTOHI9GUPgoErCFBI0agA), so you can see the TypeScript errors live.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and I solved using `Partial` as below:

Example:

```ts
interface Test {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
  d: string | undefined;
  e: string | undefined;
}

// Please note that I added Partial
type MyNewType<T> = Partial<
  {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key];
  }
>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actualy you can do it genericaly, here is a way :

**TLDR :**
improved with Matt's trick forcing other properties to be optional and never typed https://stackoverflow.com/a/66180957/15130395

```js
    type NoneOf<T> = {
        [K in keyof T]?: never;
    }

    type OnePropertyOf<T> = {
        [K in keyof T]: Omit<NoneOf<T>, K> & { [P in K]: T[P] };
    }[keyof T];
```

**Details :**

Your interface

```js
    interface Test {
        a: string;
        b: string;
        c: string;
        d: string | undefined;
        e: string | undefined;
    }
```

With this generic type :

```js
    type OnePropertyOfIntermediate<T> = {
        [K in keyof T]: { [P in K]: T[P] };
    };
```

you obtain :

```js
    {
        a: { a: string; };
        b: { b: string; };
        c: { c: string; };
        d: { d: string | undefined; };
        e: { e: string | undefined; };
    }
```

There, you just need to extract values of this object type :

```js
    type OnePropertyOf<T> = OnePropertyOfIntermediate<T>[keyof T]
```

so you get :

```js
    { a: string; } |
    { b: string; } |
    { c: string; } |
    { d: string | undefined; } |
    { e: string | undefined; };
```